SFMC - Changing Sender Authentication Package Link Question
We're changing our Sender Authentication Package (SAP) and we have link branding turned on in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. We were told by SFMC support that after the SAP cutover happens, links from any emails sent prior to the cutover will no longer work.
Has anyone encountered this issue before and if so, what did you do?
An obvious solution is to turn link tracking (i.e. branding) off. But are there any solutions for keeping link tracking in place and having old links work after changing the SAP? I greatly appreciate any help.

If you choose to apply a new SAP, it will not immediately break your links, but there is a number of items to be observed by you:

Any custom HTML Paste emails, or HTML blocks, will need to be manually updated
Any AMPscript containing URL references would need to be updated
Cloud Pages would have to be rebuilt on the new domain
The prior SAP domain will remain in place for 60 days, but after this point, old DNS records will no longer be held active by Salesforce, leading to links in emails and references to Cloud Pages on old domain will cease working.

Hence your links will remain operational until 60 days from your new SAP being applied on your account.

Thank you, Lukas. Another question for you. We're planning to use the old SAP as a private domain. Will that impact the 60 day threshold? I'm wondering if that's why we're being told the links will break immediately.

That’s a good question @ClintWoodruff - to be honest, I haven’t myself faced such a scenario before. If an SAP domain is “converted” to a private domain, it might require some immediate DNS updates, which could impact the click tracking domain. I would still challenge support asking for some more context to why the believe links will break.
